# How know my UIImage is loaded on IOS ?

Tags: ios, uiimage, image-uploading

this is my code to load my images.

```
NSString *urltest = test[@"images"][@"items"][i][@"url"];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:urltest];
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
[self.imgView setImage:img];
```

I would like to know when my is loaded. How can i do that?

Comment: Check whether `img` is nil or not. You are using synchronous call, so it will be loaded immediately

Comment: first check `if(data)img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];` and then check if you get image `if(img)[self.imgView setImage:img];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive it by,

First write this code

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(LoadImage:) withObject:@"MY URL STRING" waitUntilDone:NO];
```

And then

```
-(void)LoadImage:(NSString *) urlString
{
    /// do something when image is loading
    NSURL *imgURL=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *imgData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setImage:) withObject:imgData];
}
-(void)setImage:(NSData *) imgData;
{
    /// do something when image loading is over
    myImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
}
```

And if you want to know your image is successfully downloaded or not then use following code

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString::@"MY URL STRING"]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error){

if(error)
{
  // Error Downloading image data
}
else
{
  [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
}
}];
```

Comment: i think you should download image on `backgroundthread` and set that image on `mainthread`.

Comment: Doesn't work...
I want to do this to know when start/stop my UIActivityIndicatorView, maybe there is an other way..?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In XCode Debugger section (located at the bottom left of the XCode), you can check image object value by inserting breakpoint there. You can also **preview its value** by clicking on preview button (human eye look like button).